# How to run code when starting a rails app but not when jumping in console or using rake tasks?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I need to run some code when starting the rails server. I put the code in the `application.rb` and it works; the problem is that it runs every time I launch a rake task or I jump in `rails console`.

Is there a way to avoid this?

Comment: with an ENV variable ?. When you run your server just do `ENV_VARIABLE=whatever rails s`, and running a console `rails c` without the variable. And in your `application.rb` put your code in an `if` block like `if ENV['ENV_VARIABLE']...`

Comment: This sound like a xy problem to me. Why do you need to run a method every time the saver starts? What do you try to achieve?

Comment: What do you mean with _when starting the rails server._? Every time a server process starts? Or just the first restart after a deployment? What if you have multiple server processes or even multiple servers - do you want the command even then in all thread multiple time on each restart?

Comment: @spickermann I need to run it after every deploy, but would like to find a way to do this through the rails app and not git hooks

Comment: When you need to run the job after each _deploy_ and not on every _restart_ (depending on your server and configuration your server might restart automatically multiple times a day) then you should add this to your deploy command. How do you deploy (chef, capistrano, CD)? Where do you run your application (one server, multiple servers, PAAS)?

Comment: @spickermann Yeah you are right. I got a manually written bash script, will insert this there.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a good start:

```
Rails.const_defined?(:Server)
```

Comment: ...and a good finish? Will the :Server constant be defined only when launching server?